# Does QGIS perform better when using a materialized view or a standard view from PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, performance, sql-view

My PostGIS views in QGIS are significantly slower then other standard PostGIS tables and I have struggled to enhance their performance any good amount. If using materialized views in QGIS would I expect performance to increase?

Comment: There's really no way to tell with the information provided. Pick a specific view. Describe the component tables (row counts and cardinality). Describe the join columns and indexes available Report the the resulting row count and timing (in milliseconds or seconds). Provide the EXPLAIN query plan.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, using a materialized view (MV) **with proper indexing** will be either as efficient as a regular view, or better. It can't be slower.

MV start to become truly more efficient if the index on the underlying view table(s) can't be used, or if costly computations are done in the select.

BUT, MV are not free either, you need to refresh them as the data change. MV can be seen as having a new table/layer, with the convenience of being refresh-able. This convenience is a poisoned one (as of current version, Postgres 13) because multiple workers can't be used during a refresh (but can during the MV creation), which can lead to extremely long refresh time in case of heavy computations (I personally drop-recreate the MV rather than refresh them).

Comment: An MV *can* slow performance if use of them blows out the block buffer cache, causing file I/O on what could have been a cache hit. It depends on the size of the tables (individually and cumulatively), the size of the MV and the RAM available to the server.

Comment: Maybe one for e new question. But why use a materialized view at all if you are dropping/recreating. Why not just create a table?

Comment: 1) A MV doesn't take space in DB dumps / backup. 2) For consistency with the other (simpler) MV that gets simply refreshed, and 3) to make it clear that it is derived data. Someone could just run the (slow) refresh without having to know the underlying code/query.